# Use of conditional formating using formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

In cell M100; I would like to color the cell GREEN if c100-f100+g100 = j100toj109.  If they are not equal color cell RED

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? SU is not a personal scripting service.

Comment: in cell M100   =if( (c100-f100+g100) <> (sum(j100:109)), RED, GREEN)

Comment: Googled: conditional formatting formula, first result: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the cells default color to RED
2. Use this formula to create the conditional formatting rule

   > =C100-F100+G100=SUM(J100:J109)
3. Change the format in the conditional formatting box to GREEN